# No sound after fresh install

Tags: drivers, sound, video, via, openchrome

lspci shows me this: 
`80:01.0 Audio device: VIA Technologies, Inc. VT8237A/VT8251 HDA Controller (rev 10)` 
I have openchrome installed (it appears installed in the software center) but I can't hear any sounds.

As you can see my sound card is a VIA 64MB. I know I can't expect much, but listening to music should be OK. I installed Ubuntu 11.04, and immediately upgraded to 11.10.

I think that with my video card, I can't use Unity 3d (right now I'm using unity 2d), but when I go to System Info > graphics section, it shows me: `Driver: unknown`. It seems to me that via graphics drivers are not working nor are sounds via drivers.

Comment: Try using this guide: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1iTlJ8BfqXUjaHO__TEdlkvuqB1WLOkGaudngc5SFLMI/edit

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!